# How to detect if URL is returning ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: php

Is there a way to use `PHP` to detect if some URL is returning `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`?

Is this even possible?

Comment: You could check the status code of the request and if 504 that should be time out.

Comment: The `URL` doesn't returns any status

Comment: The phrasing _"if some URL is returning ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"_ makes little sense to begin with. The URL is not "returning" anything here (how could it, when the requester could not even establish a _connection_.) This is an error shown by your _client_, because _it_ decided after after a certain amount of time in which it was not able to make a connection, to break the whole process off at this point. // PHP cURL for example has the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT / CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS options - but the _value_ is something you will have to specify.